# Optimization for large strings C/C++

Tags: c, string, reduce

I'm looking for a way to optimize my implementation. Basically this is a "reduce"-like (from Map Reduce framework) function. It takes a key and its values. The goal is to check all the values if they are distinct and output them in a form of an list: value1;value2;value3;...valuen; as a string. n can be very large (in 1000s)

```
void unique(char *key, int keybytes, char *multivalue, int nvalues,

        int *valuebytes, KeyValue *kv, void *ptr) {

    char * value = NULL;
    char * elem[nvalues];

    int i, j, cx;
    char adj[3858905] = "";
```

Big problem is that I have to specify char adj[] length for every input and I don't know ahead how big a number of values is. (That takes huge amount of memory)

```
    for (i = 0; i < nvalues; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            value = multivalue;
        } else {
            value = multivalue + valuebytes[i - 1];
            multivalue = multivalue + valuebytes[i - 1];
        }
        elem[i] = value;
    }

    size_t elem_length = sizeof(elem)/sizeof(char *);
    qsort(elem, elem_length, sizeof(char *), cstring_cmp);

    cx = sprintf(adj, "%s;", elem[0]);

    j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < nvalues; i++) {
        bool matching = false;
        if (!strcmp(elem[i], elem[j]))
            matching = true;
        j++;
        if (!matching) //{;}
            cx += snprintf(adj + cx, 3858905 - cx - 1, "%s;", elem[i]);                                             
    }
```

adj is an output string - list of values.

```
    kv->add(key, keybytes, adj, strlen(adj) + 1); //this outputs key-value pairs.
}
```

I have to use C/C++ only though.

Comment: feels like homework ... is it?

Comment: @AhmedMasud, no, it's part of my work project

Comment: do you know how to use malloc?

Comment: Is the issue that you need to write to a string, but you don't know how big the string is going to be until you've written it, and therefore you don't know how much to allocate?

Comment: @VaughnCato yes, 1. string's length is unknown, 2. as it gets really huge char adj[] takes a lot of memory.

Comment: I think the basic *standard* approach is just to double the string (and copy) each time more space is required. It's amortized O(1). I wouldn't be surprised if there was such a [non-standard] library to do as such or something similar for "growing strings".

Comment: @AhmedMasud, not sure how to use it for this particular case

Comment: If you can use C++, how about using std::ostringstream?  It automatically increases the string size as necessary as you write to it.

Comment: why dont you use malloc, calloc combination to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Huffman Codification. It's a complex thing and old, but I think that's efficient. I don't know if there's new or/and better algorithms to do that.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/huffman.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: That can make the storage smaller (though not in all cases), but it doesn't solve the problem of not knowing in advance how big the string is going to be.

Comment: I don't know if the problem is the complexity of storage or if hits the maximum memory. If it does that, it needs a secondary memory thing and can take a huge time to do that. Or if the problem it's the length of the vector (you don't know how much memory you have to allocate), amortized complexity things can solve in a relative easier way. If you don't need to index or to sort, you can do a list (it's complicated but you can put something and erase quickly). If you need to check distinct values previously know, a hash-table it's a good idea. You have a lot of options depending of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};
```

i suggest to use linked list to store all the values and then convert it into string...

you can keep count of number of stored values in linked list and using that calculate the string length...and then allocate enough memory using malloc().....

and later on..while more values are added to list you can modify the memory allocated using calloc()....

i dont know if its what you exactly wanted....but it looks feasible to me